# How to achieve code similar to for loop from Oracle in SQL Server?

Tags: oracle, loops, for-loop, sql-server-2017

I have some code from Oracle. I want to execute similar code in SQL Server.

This is my current Oracle code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
 NEW(V_IN IN VARCHAR2, 
   V_PATH 
   OUT VARCHAR2)IS
  BEGIN
   FOR ITEM IN(SELECT 
   V.A||'\'||T.B AS 
   V_PATH FROM TABLE1 T 
   INNER JOIN VIEW1 V ON 
   V.ID= T.FID WHERE 
   T.FID='12a')
```

How can write code which works similarly to this in SQL Server?

Comment: This code will not even work in oracle. In select query of the for loop, INTO is not allowed.

Comment: @Tejash  took "as" in place of into. It is now working

Comment: In SQL Server, there is no FOR LOOP. However, you simulate the FOR LOOP using the WHILE LOOP.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate FOR LOOP with WHILE LOOP. Here an example

```
    DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < 10
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Inside simulated FOR LOOP';
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;

PRINT 'Done simulated FOR LOOP';
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor

```
IF OBJECT_ID('NEW', 'P') IS NOT NULL
  DROP PROCEDURE NEW;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE 
 NEW(@V_IN VARCHAR(4000), 
   @V_PATH 
   VARCHAR(4000) OUT)AS
  BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
   DECLARE ITEM CURSOR FOR SELECT 
   ISNULL(V.A, '')+''+ISNULL(T.B, '') AS 
   V_PATH FROM TABLE1 T 
   INNER JOIN VIEW1 V ON 
   V.ID= T.FID WHERE 
   T.FID='12a';
```